# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'isalpha'

Tags: python, attributeerror

When I try to use the "isalpha()" function like here:

```py
def find_chars(string):
  num_letter = 0
  num_int = 0
  num_spec = 0

  for i in string:
    i_str = i.lower
    if i_str.isalpha():
      num_str +=1 
    elif i.isdigit():
      num_int += 1
    else:
      num_spec += 1
  return num_letter, num_int, num_spec
```

I get the following

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'isalpha'
```

I am using python 3.6.9 if that helps (using google colab)

Comment: You forgot your parentheses: `i_str = i.lower`

Comment: add paranthesis, change `i_str = i.lower` to `i_str = i.lower()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line above

```
i_str = i.lower
```

should be:

```
i_str = i.lower()
```

The type of `i_str` changed to function with that assignment.

Answer (score 1):

As user2357112 supports Monica says, you forgot the parenthesis in `i.lower`

```py
def find_chars(string):
  num_letter = 0
  num_int = 0
  num_spec = 0

  for i in string:
    i_str = i.lower()  # <-- Added parenthesis
    if i_str.isalpha():
      num_str +=1 
    elif i.isdigit():
      num_int += 1
    else:
      num_spec += 1
  return num_letter, num_int, num_spec
```

Since you forgot the parenthesis, you're assigning a function to a variable, so when you try to execute `i_str.isalpha()`, the variable (which is now containing a function) doesn't have the `isalpha()` method like strings do.